# Rename all selectors in all HTML, CSS and JS by pattern (add prefixes to selectors)

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, postcss

I have a static website: **HTML**, **CSS**, **JS** files and **no back-end** programming. Parts of this website will be injected into another website. So I need to make sure that new CSS file from my project will not corrupt an old one and vice versa.

One of the things I need to do is to rename all selectors like so:

```
<button class="button">
```

to

```
<button class="my-button">
```

**and**

```
.button {
    background: blue;
}
```

to

```
.my-button {
    background: blue;
}
```

**and**

```
$('.button').on('click');
```

to

```
$('.my-button).on('click');
```

Preferably with **GULP** or **postCSS** but any other way will work too. Is there any GULP plugins? So far I found only for CSS.

Thanks.

Comment: Use your text editor to rename.

Comment: Why you don't use notepad++ replaceALL function?

Comment: Well... there is a lot of code and lots of different selectors.

Comment: did u manage to do this?

Comment: @BalaSivagnanam Now I see this in my code. Try to google such plugins. My task was resolved but I can't remember how "good" my solution was. I still have a bad feeling about it :)

`var name        = require('gulp-rename');
var rework      = require('gulp-rework');
var reworkNPM   = require('rework-npm');
var classPrefix = require('rework-class-prefix');`

Answer (score 1):

This is only for the CSS part, but I don't think there's an automated way for you anyway:

I'd try a different approach. I'm sure your included website will sit inside a container. If it's an iframe, you don't have any danger of collisions anyway - no need to do anything.

To make sure things don't collide if included right in another HTML document, proceed as follows:

1. Rename all your *.css files to *.scss
2. Create a new files "includes.scss" which will include all your renamed css files (make sure it's the correct order):

   `.my-website {
     @import("header.scss");
     @import("main.scss");
     @import("footer.scss");
   }`

This will put all included files in a class context so the rules contained only affect elements inside the `.my-website` container.

Comment: No it is not gonna be iframe. There will be normal pages and they will have components from both projects. Thanks for the idea to wrap it into **of .my-website** but, again, it will not help in my case.

Comment: CSS is actually an easiest part. I found [this plugin](https://github.com/johnotander/rework-class-prefix) to add prefixes. There is a [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-prefix-css) to add **!important** to properties (it will resolve opposite problem) and all other stuff. But so far I see nothing for HTML or JS.